# Adding Break in Dot Border

Tags: html, css, border

I am working on a website design based upon a company's print branding, and one aspect that I'd like to mimic is the break in the dot border for a header surrounding the content. [(Here's an example.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr4Bq.jpg) As you can see, the header text is vertically centered against the dot border, so half of it sits above the edge, and the length of the break will differ based upon the word length (though the amount of white space before and after each word should be consistent). In some instances, like the one in the photo, there will be multiple headers in the same rectangle, so it won't just be the top border that needs to be addressed. The background in this design will be an image, not a solid color. In addition, this site is responsive so will require the workaround to function in various mobile environments, and the width of the border will vary as the space changes.

I'm primarily a web designer with some front end coding abilities, but nothing too advanced, so I'm wondering if this is possible (in general, and for my experience level) or if I should just change the design entirely. Any suggestions?

Edit: I've added a new photo to clarify my question, still hoping there is a feasible way to do this with a photographic background element. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, try to make header display: inline block, add side
 padding to it and color with it's parent background. After that you can
 raise this header to top with it's half-height. For example:

1) Position: relative; line-height: 1em: top: -.5em;
2) Transform: translateY(-50%);

Here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/5w4hanu3/2/

```
h2 {
  position: relative;

  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

.top h2,
.bottom h2 {
  transform: translateY(-50%);

  padding: 0 20px;

  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Ack I forgot to add that the background is not white, it is a full bleed image (wood texture), I made the example image white without thinking, sorry about that. So yeah that would have been a good fix except that the solid color background won't work in this design, unfortunately :/